# How to install psrchive on windows?

Tags: python, module

As given in the website https://psrchive.sourceforge.net/manuals/python/, I have downloaded the psrchive folder from github, and now is not sure what to do for installation. Can someone explain it to me how to install it, as I am not making sense of what is written in the instructions.

I'm not sure how to install psrchive for use in python.

Comment: After installing(pip install psrchive), you can add it to your project and use it.

Comment: @AnılhanHasceviz Its not getting installed, it shows me the error package not found.